# How can i change the language of native dialog elements of the tabris ios client?

Tags: ios, eclipse, tabris

How is it possible to change the language of native dialog elements of the tabris ios client ?

For Example i will change the language of the Cancel-Button of the context menu. Can i do this in XCode or in an other way ?

The error messages from the ASIHTTPFramework which are used in tabris are only in english. It was nice to change the languages of these messages but how ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localization **for the Client** is not part of the upcoming 1.0 release. We will provide the ability to localize the few hardcoded strings (OK, Cancel, Done, ...) on the client at a later point...